# sudo start program as user with encrypted home

Tags: sudo, encryption, home-directory

I am logged in as user1 and want to start a program1 with sudo user2:

```
sudo -u user2 program1
```

But home of user2 is encrypted. So program1 exits because it can't write to it's settings folder. How can I solve this problem?

One solution to this problem is to use

```
ssh -X user2 program1
```

But I am interested if it is also possible with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could just login as the other user (`login` in a terminal is fine), thus decrypting their home, and run programs successfully. Apparently your `ssh -X` idea should do that, but doesn't appear necessary for a local user.
2. Tell the program you're trying to run (`program1` in your example) to use a different folder, one that's currently mounted / writeable. How to do that would vary according to each program. Maybe using a "dummy" home folder might work, a temporary link, etc.
3. Manually decrypt / mount the other user's home. You'd need to know their login passphrase (or actual mount key) and I'm sure just logging in as the other user would be easier.